# Compose Android Label to circle

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to create a label that will act as a tag to add when a new item is added, so I want this Label put the text "New" and after 4 seconds it converts the label to a circle (acting as a notification badge icon) what I've tried is :

```
@Composable
internal fun AnimatedNewLabel() {
    var showText by remember { mutableStateOf("New") }
    var padding by remember { mutableStateOf(8.dp) }
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .drawBehind {
                drawCircle(
                    color = Color.Red,
                    radius = this.size.maxDimension,
                )
            }
            .padding(start = 8.dp, top = 8.dp, end = 12.dp, bottom = 8.dp),
        text = showText,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        maxLines = 1,
        fontSize = 14.sp,
        lineHeight = 20.sp,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
    )
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        delay(4000)
        showText = ""
        padding = 0.dp
    }
}
```

But is not looking smooth, is there any other way to do this? I've checked there's a modifier also for autosizeText but don't know if it's they way to use this.

Answer (score 0):

To make it smooth you must use Compose's animation helpers to animate size or colors. This codelab [Animation in Compose](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-animation#0) is great.

It's a bit hard to understand what you are asking for, but this is an example of a text animating smoothly to a circle, adapt as you need:
**animateDpAsState** will animate the dp size from 0 to 40.

```
@Composable
fun LabelCircle() {
    var showText by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        delay(4000)
        showText = false
    }

    val circleSize by animateDpAsState(
        targetValue = if (showText) 0.dp else 40.dp,
        animationSpec = spring(),
    )
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.size(40.dp),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    ) {
        if (showText) {
            Text("New")
        }
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.clip(CircleShape).size(circleSize).background(Color.Red),
        ) {
        }
    }
}
```